# different result aes encrypt between mysql and codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

select AES_ENCRYPT('sabar', 'sabar');
result
hÕ
nkPRºY]°c Z

meanwhile in codeigniter
$this->encryption->initialize(
array(
'cipher' => 'aes-128',
'mode' => 'ecb',
'key' => 'sabar',
'driver' => 'openssl'
)
);
$plain_text = 'sabar';
$ciphertext = $this->encryption->encrypt($plain_text);

result :
741887b53ee48b723a60ed6d11732327c011b0845e353682560250ca4a39663271360a09a539a088394103676b9a2f34dd7d15944a552c5a7e489cf0eaa2f1688vgNYQg7HYhTq21jY0Nc2w==

how i get same result. and when descrpty on mysql or codeigniter result is same.

thanks for help

Comment: What is the question? MySQL and Codeigniter use AES in two different mechanisms.

Comment: nah... i want when encrypt by mysql can decrypt by codeigniter. or encrypt by codeigniter can decrypt by mysql.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with doing this. Mysql is giving the output in a hexadecimal format. it is not binary text. While php is simply encrypting it and giving an output.You cant simply convert the two. There are some work involved. I hope this link can help you. It explains this better than I can just by giving you a piece of code.

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/replicating-mysql-aes-encryption-methods-with-php/